# Oracle connectivity for Selenium using Python

Tags: python, oracle, selenium

I am using selenium with Python.
I recorder the test case and able to run it properly.
Now the web page I am  using is connect with oracle server and some details thae need to be provide in Web page is required to fetch from oracle DB.

So can you please help that how to fetch data from oracle and fill the web page details automatically in selenium

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask the people who wrote the application how you can connect to the Oracle database. They can provide you with the database schema, the connection URL with user name and password.

After that, you need to add the Oracle driver to your Selenium project and create helper classes to fetch data from the database. Use those helper classes in your page object.

[This page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle) contains links to Python drivers for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I have the Oracle db details like user name , schema etc . I need to know how can I use python to connect to Oracle DB and used the fetched data from DB to selenium web page.

Comment: I've added a link to a page that lists Python drivers for Oracle.

Comment: I m using windows for python and Oracle is installed on Linux box

Comment: All drivers should be able to access Oracle remotely. If you have a specific problem, feel free to open a new question.